# Setting button disabled to result of string compare in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Right now I have:

```
<button ng-click="doSomething()" ng-disabled="{{aVariable}} != 'Ready'">Button 1</button>
```

Where aVariable is initially set to 'Ready' and subsequently set to an integer then back to Ready.

But the button won't disable/enable based on the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself. Should've used:

```
<button ng-click="doSomething()" ng-disabled="aVariable != 'Ready'">Button 1</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

`ng-disabled` doesn't required interpolation directive `{{}}`, you can directly use angular `scope` variables inside directive for solving expressions

**Markup**

```
<button ng-click="doSomething()" ng-disabled="aVariable != 'Ready'">Button 1</button>
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.